# how to use return type to Return the result in the form of List/Array

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, function

I want my method getobject to return the result which can be looked upon by addressing the index number of the result. I thought of using an array, but then I switched to list.  Which is the best method for this type of problem? How do I return the value to getobject method because I'm getting cannot convert type error.

```
private String[] getobject(string source, sqlconnection conn)
{
    sqlcommand command = new sqlcommand("select*from ABC");
    sqlreader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    List<string> dbname = new List<string>();
    while(reader.read())
    {
         dbname = reader.getString(1);
    }
    return dbname;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `List<string>` to build up your list is a good choice.  If you want to return an array you can use the `ToArray` method.

```
private string[] getobject(string source, SqlConnection conn)
{
   var command = new SqlCommand("select * from ABC");
   var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
   var output = new List<string>();
   while(reader.Read())
   {
       output.Add(reader.GetString(1));
   }
      return output.ToArray();
}
```

This will convert the `List<string>` to a `string[]`.